# AnythingSlider Static Link takes 2 clicks the first time

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-plugins, anythingslider

I'm having a strange issue with AnythingSlider, this is my page layout:
[image]

The red blocks being links. The Biggest red block in the big middle black  requires two clicks in FireFox and the BlackBerry browser but only one in Chrome/IE (IE!?). The other red boxes (Links) only need one click in ALL browsers.

Any help would be awesome guys!

Comment: It is difficult to help troubleshoot this problem without any code to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, at least in the version that I am using: AnythingSlider v1.8.6,
 I had same problem, but when setting hashTags to false links are now working ;)

```
 $('#slider').anythingSlider({

     hashTags: false

   });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT fixable, its just the way it works after much research.